# KoaJS Middleware. Return response but also invoke next()

Tags: node.js, koa

I have three middlewares called A,B & C.

There are certain requests which are long running tasks on the server.

In that case, when going downstream, I want my middleware B to immediately return a HTTP Code 202 Accepted that goes through middleware A upstream. I also need to invoke middleware C downstream from middleware B. Once middleware C completes, I want to invoke it upstream, and I also want to invoke middleware B Upstream (at this point, I don't care if middleware A is invoked upstream or not).

Is there a way to do this?

Psuedo-code:

```
const koa = require('koa');
const app = new koa();

/* some routes defined 
//
//
*/

//MW A
app.use(async (ctx,next) => {
    //do something
    await next();
    //do something
});

//MW B
app.use(async (ctx,next) => {
    if (!longRunningTask)    //proceed as normal
        //do something
        await next();
        //do something
    else {
        /* Here I want to return immediately return ctx.status = 202, so it goes upstream through Middleware A, but I also want to invoke next, so that request goes through middleware C's downstream and upstream, as well as middleware B's upstream */

        //return ctx.status = 202;
        //do something
        //await next();
        //so something
    }
});

//MW C
app.use(async (ctx,next) => {
     //do something;
     return;
});
```

Comment: It sounds like your middleware is ordered improperly or the design is wonky.  You should not be running more middleware after you send a response. Perhaps the middleware that sends a response should be last or perhaps you should just call some function with some shared code in it from the middleware that sends a response.

Comment: Perhaps. The issue I am trying to solve is preventing a HTTP Timeout on the client. 99% of the requests that the client will send will be processed by the sever in under 1s. However, there are a few queries that will take a long time (> 10 minutes). I do not want that client to wait upon that. I want the server to inform the client that the task is underway, freeing him; in the meantime, the server does the stuff as it usually does - which means invoking middlewares normally.